# A bunch of circles and squares

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The grey region is simply the region you see below.

The answer will give you 10 letters.

---

[image]

**US's:**

### [image]
TSDFCK

### [image]
RTOYLG

### [image]
AWQMRZ

### [image]
PUWSTU

### [image]
SRNXEL

---

Hint 1:

> Added "mathematics-tag". Nothing fancy, but still some mathematical knowledge is required.

Hint 2

> For the bottom part; You will have to do some small calculations (or maybe it's not even necessary. For some, just a look at them can be enough.) But first of all you have to make sense of the top image. What can it possibly represent?

Comment: I think IN is better expressed as QI.

Comment: rot13(V'z nffhzvat gubfr erq yvarf ner rkcerffvat pbatehrapl?)

Comment: @DertereuuiFloireiurtrthr No, its not. You need to make sense of the top image first.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Got the top but the simplest path for the bottom gave 18 or 12 random letters. I'll think some more, hopefully not a puzzle error.

Comment: @Amoz Ok. Yes, it will give you 10 letters once you see how to interpret the bottom.

Comment: rot13 Vf gur erq fznyy yvar bire gur yrsg obeqre bs CHJFGH vagragvbany?

Comment: rot13 Qbrf guvf unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu nfgebabzl?

Comment: @VictorStafusa No, the size difference of the red lines in the squares should all be considered equal. It doesn't matter. And no, not about astronomy.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLtLC.png

Comment: @VictorStafusa Aah, I see. But no, not intentional. Used a simple/bad editor via phone when doing this puzzle. Don't have access to laptop atm. So just ignore that small line.

Comment: rot13(Nz V fhccbfrq gb trg PBHGHER be vf guvf bss genpx? Sbe fbzr ernfba V pna'g svther bhg ubj gb rkgenpg gur zhpu zber boivbhf cuenfr...)

Comment: @Amoz No, that answer is not on the right track. I'll add another hint in a couple of days and if it's still unsolved you can always post a partial ofc

Comment: @Prim3numbah A few us seem to think we have solved the first part but still can't get the second part. Is the first part rot13(?? = PA) and rot13(HF'f = havg fdhnerf)?

Comment: @cap Yes, both are correct.

Comment: @cap Now it's a matter of somehow make the bottom make sense given the information from the top image... do you have an idea maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original Partial Answer (Complete Answer below this one):

Weeks ago I figured out that the gray section "IN" means

> irrational numbers (I hope).

thinking that the values in order are

> ??, Real Numbers, Irrational Numbers, Rational Numbers, Integers, Natural Numbers

At first I thought the slopes of the lines might be important but I couldn't make anything out of those, but when I saw in the comments that

> U.S. means unit square, I looked at the line length values

The values for each image are:

> Image 1: $\sqrt{2}/2$, $\sqrt{5/4}$, $1/2$, $\sqrt{2}$, $1$, $\sqrt{2}/2$
>  Image 2: $\sqrt{5/4}$, $\sqrt{5/4}$, $1$, $1/2$, $\sqrt{2}/2$, $\sqrt{2}/2$
>  Image 3: $\sqrt{5/4}$, $\sqrt{5/4}$, $\sqrt{2}/2$, $1/2$, $\sqrt{2}/2$, $\sqrt{2}/2$
>  Image 4: $\sqrt{2}$, $1$, $1/2$, $1/2$, $1$, $1$
>  Image 5: $\sqrt{2}$, $1$, $\sqrt{2}/2$, $\sqrt{5/4}$, $1$, $\sqrt{5/4}$

I thought that each image's line marking (I through IIIIII) could correspond to

> the letter in the string to the right of each image, in order.

I first thought that maybe the lengths that are

> irrational numbers correspond to the correct letters, but that gives me more than 10 letters, since 18 of the 30 lengths are irrational.

So I then tried to make the letters corresponding to the

> 12 rational numbers fit somehow, but with no luck.

Then, grasping at straws, I had the idea of choosing only the lengths that had

> no integer component i.e. $\sqrt{2}/2$, although irrational, would be ignored because it was divided by an integer. This method did yield 10 letters: S,F; R,T; A,W; P; S,X,L. However, I have not been able to make anything of it, so it is extremely likely that this is not the solution.

EDIT:
OK, I've finally got it!

Using some hints in the comments, we must apply

> Natural Numbers (NN) to the first square, Integers (I) to the second square, and so on.

From the first square, the

> fifth value, C, is a natural number (1)

From the second square, the

> third value, O, is an integer (1)

From the third square, the

> fourth value, M, is rational (1/2)

From the fourth square, the

> first value, P, is irrational ($\sqrt{2}$)

From the fifth square,

> all of the values are real numbers, so all of them are chosen (S,R,N,X,E,L)

That leaves us with these ten letters:

> C,O,M,P,S,R,N,X,E,L

When we reverse the order of the last 6 letters (Thanks @user39583), we get

> COMPLEXNRS (Complex numbers, which is the answer to ??)

Comment: rot13(V'z nffhzvat V jbhyq or "vagrtref" naq gur ?? jbhyq yvxryl or PA sbe pbzcyrk ahzoref.)

Comment: @SQLNoob Yeah I meant integers! And I saw cn in the comments, but I wasn't too focused on either because I assumed this puzzle was only dealing with IN, but who knows.

Comment: On 2nd thought, maybe cn does fit in, since it is ?? in the puzzle.

Comment: @user39583 That's as far as I got, but I assumed it was an easter egg since it doesn't make sense to me why IN specifically is gray and "below", but not say RN

Comment: Bu znlor orpnhfr vg pyhrf gur jbeq 'va'. Gung pbhyq znxr frafr.

Comment: You're correct that the lines represent qvfgnaprf. Ohg zl vqrn bs gur pvepyrf jvguva n pvepyr jvguva n pvepyr... jnf gung rnpu yrggre/yrggre-cnve (ahzore frg) pbeerfcbaqrq gb qvssrerag pvepyrf. AA, gur svefg frg, pbeerfcbaqrq gb rirelguvat vafvqr gur fznyyrfg pvepyr. V, gur frpbaq frg, pbeerfcbaqrq gb rirelguvat vafvqr gur frpbaq fznyyrfg pvepyr.. rgp. Ohg veengvbany ahzoref qba'g pbeerfcbaq gb rirelguvat vafvqr gur 4gu pvepyr, fb V pubfr gb cnvag guvf ertvba terl. Gur qvntenz jnf zrnag gb ercerfrag n frg jvguva n frg jvguva n frg.. rgp. Fb vg'f abguvat fcrpvny nobhg VA (veengvbany ahzoref).

Comment: See the comment of user39583 above

Comment: Now it looks good. Well done

Comment: @Prim3numbah It was driving me crazy! haha. Thx for the puzzle.